# How can I load data from API to page on onload event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Ajax call using JQuery  Ajax call using JQuery

Answer (score 0):

You can store the values in `localStorage` to retain them and append it to `textbox` as needed:

```
$(document).on('ready' ,function(){
    var value=localStorage.getItem('symbols'); //get value from localStorage
    if(value!="" && typeof value != undefined) //check if it has value or not
           $("#inputSymbol").val(value) //set input text's value

    $("form").submit(function(){
        var valueEnteredByUser = $("#inputSymbol").val();
        var valueToBeStored=localStorage.getItem('symbols') + ' ' + valueEnteredByUser;
        //here I am storing values with space separate and you have to take care how you want to store it actually
        localStorage.setItem('symbols',valueToBeStored); //Store it in same localStorage.
        //var valueEnteredByUser = "GE";


        if (valueEnteredByUser == null || valueEnteredByUser == ""){
              alert("Please enter a valid symbol");
           }
        new Request.symbolExecution(valueEnteredByUser, function(data) {
            $("#dataContainer").remove();
            this.success(data);

        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Now at any point of time if you want to remove value just do as below:

```
localStorage.setItem('symbols','') //store empty value
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make the AJAX call right away inside your `$(document).ready()` block and push it onto a table that has the `style="visibility:hidden;"` that way the API call can begin before rendering takes place. Next I would set the `hidden` table to `show` during the `$(window).load()` function (which occurs after 'ready').

It may looks something like this:

```
$(document).on('ready', function(){
    //AJAX API Here

    // On success push data to table (hidden style)

});

$(window).load(function(){
    //$(.hiddenTable).show();
});
```

This should provide a good user experience since the data will begin retreival from the API before the page is even rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make the first call through `php` and then the rest of the keys through `js`, as you said you want the data that is available through "GE" key as the *default*, you could get that data by using [CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) or [get_file_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).